# MyEclipse: Changing Android codes takes no effect

Tags: android, ide, myeclipse

I know this is a rare question. Even if there are people using MyEclipse for Android development is doubted :(

The annoying thing is that after I modified my Android project (like an Activity class of a xml file), the project remained the same as it was when I imported it.

I thought there is an important feature that demonstrates this error: When I run my Android project and the console reported that "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front". This line occurs because the project didnt changed while as a matter of fact I did change the project and saved it.

Is there anyone has the same problem like me?

-------------add in Oct. 28-------------------

This was what I did: first, I modified one of my activities by commenting out the Toast functions; and then, I ran it however the Toast line still showed on my Genymotion emulator

Comment: when this error show in logcat . backpress on you mobile app.

Comment: What release of MyEclipse are you using? Have you installed additional plug-ins (note that MyEclipse 2015 CI provides increasingly functional mobile tools, built in). Also the actual steps you took would be help to replicate your issue.

Comment: MyEclipse 10 is my current version. This was what I did: first, I modified one of my activities by commenting out the Toast functions; and then, I ran it however the Toast line still showed on my Genymotion emulator.@TonyWeddle

Comment: I have specified my questions@AnikIslamAbhi